# "containment:parent" is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, physics-engine, throwable

I've created a demo page that generates a masonry-style layout from several divs, and then after x seconds runs the jquery.throwable script on said divs.

Here it is:  http://output.jsbin.com/yitaru/2/

The problem I've run into is that throwable's "containment:parent" option is not working.  The divs themselves are living within multiple parent divs - a ".grid" class (used by the grid generator plugin) and a ".container" class.  Neither one seems to be recognized as a parent though, at least by throwable.  The divs fall through the bottom of the container and continue falling down the page.  Instead I want them to stop within the bounds of the red border.

Any idea what the issue might be here?  I expect this is related to a CSS issue and not-so-much a problem with throwable, but I don't know enough about how CSS works to figure this one out on my own.  I thought that by nesting the divs in eachother, the parent/child structure would be defined.

Comment: Also - details on jquery.throwable and it's options are here: https://github.com/benahm/jquery.throwable  That page says "containment: define the limits where the object can be thrown 
                   "window" is the default
                   "parent" the object will be contained inside the parent
                   you can specify custom containment by giving array [x1,y1,x2,y2]"

Answer (score 0):

What a dummy!  containment:"parent" did not include the quotes around "parent".  Problem fixed.